# Does anyone know if an onboard RAID chip (LSI MegaRAID) the maximum drive it can support?

Tags: storage

I have an ASUS Z10PE-D16/4L motherboard, which has an onboard LSI MegaRAID chip. Anybody know how many drives it support. Looked up the manual, but it does not say.

Also, if I get a dedicated RAID card, does anybody if I can mix and match use both the SATA ports on the motherboard itself and  the RAID SATA/SAS ports on the dedicated RAID card?

Comment: What is a Z10PE-D16/4L?

Comment: it's the motherboard, ASUS 10PE-D16/4L

Comment: You should clarify a little: What do you mean by "mix and match use"? Will an OS be able to use all drives? Probably yes. Will the RAID controller be able to use them all for an array? Probably no. - With the motherboard, counting the sockets may help to get an estimate of the number of supported drives...